# How to read complex numbers from a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, complex-numbers

I want to read from a file a set of complex numbers into an array,using Python. I know how to do it only for integers. I tried this,but when I run it ,it says: complex() arg is a malformed string. How can I do to read complex numbers? I just started to learn Python.

```
f=open("file.txt","r+")
array=[]
for line in f:
     line=line.split()
     if line: 
            line=[complex(i) for i in line]
```

My file contains only complex numbers:

```
1+i
1-i
1
2
-3
```

Comment: Please post some part of your file as well.

Comment: On my file I have 5 complex numbers: 1+i ,1-i, 1,2 and -3; but there are written one per line,without comma between.

Comment: @israell you need to show the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an engineer's `j` instead of a mathematician's `i` for the imaginary unit in python.

You can change something simple like:

```
line = line.replace('i', 'j').split()
```

instead of the `line=line.split()` you have currently, this should fix your code.

Note, there is no need to `.split()` at all if you have truly one number per line, and you still need to append the results into your container `array`.  I'll leave that bit to you.

As an aside, consider using `numpy.loadtxt` to parse your file instead, if you have numpy available.